# How to use ASCII codes to create uppercase strings in C programming language

Tags: c

I have a function in C as follows

```
char    *ft_strupcase(char *str)
{
    int i;

    i = 0;
    while (str[i] != '\0')
    {
        if (str[i] >= 'a' && str[i] <= 'z')
        {
            str[i] -= 32;
        }
        i++;
    }
    return (str);
}
```

which converts lowercase letter in the string to upper case. I want to achieve the same but using ASCII values instead. My code is

```
char    *ft_strupcase(char *str)
{
    int index;
    index = 0;
    while (str[index] != '\0')
    {
        if (str[index] < 97 && str[index] < 122)
        {
            str[index] = str[index] - str[32];
        }
    ++index;
    }
    return str;
}
```

which gives me a error

```
Bad permissions for mapped region at address 0x400657at 0x40057B: ft_strupcase
```

which I don't understand why. According to my understanding if the char on the string is "a" then my code should convert it to "A" as 97 -32 = 65 which is an ASCII for A . I am lost as to what I am doing wrong. Any guidance is highly appreciated

Comment: `str[32]` - This access the 33-th character of the string `str`, which is beyond its end.

Comment: "but using ASCII values instead" Why? Do you intent to create low quality code? Using magic numbers instead of the character they represent is bad practice.

Comment: Are you calling the function by passing a string litteral (which is constant)?

Comment: `- str[32];` You want `- 32` as with our first code

Comment: In second code block you're substracting two ASCII (with out of bounds UB), I doubt this is what you wanted, if you want to substrat the offset (between uppercase range and lowercase range) from a character, first example is correct

Comment: And you mean `if (str[index] >= 97 && str[index] <= 122` instead of `if (str[index] < 97 && str[index] < 122`

Comment: The correct way is to subratct `32` not some unknown character that might randomly appear at index `32` in an array that might not even be that large

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Insure `str` does **not** point to a *string literal***

```
char *bad = "Test";    
ft_strupcase(bad);  // UB

char good[] = "Test";    
ft_strupcase(good);  // OK
```

**Wrong compare**

**Wrong offset**

`str[32]` is not the difference between lower and upper case ASCII characters.  That is some element of array `str[]`.

**Avoid naked [magic numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_(programming))**

---

```
    //if (str[index] < 97 && str[index] < 122) {
    //    str[index] = str[index] - str[32];
    //}

    #define ASCIIA 65
    #define ASCIIa 97
    #define ASCIIz 122
    if (str[index] >= ASCIIa && str[index] <= ASCIIz) {
        str[index] = str[index] - ASCIIa + ASCIIA;
    }
```

---

It really makes more sense to use `'a'` instead of `ASCIIa` or `97`.  Same for the other constants.

The only reason for not using `'a'` is to make the source code portable to non-ASCII source code environments (rare these days) yet still handle ASCII input.